# Side by Side versioning of web hosted Windows Workflows Services 4.5

Tags: service, workflow

I was trying to get the Side by side workflow services to work  ( followed the MSDN article.. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh314045%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Unfortunately my persisted workflows broke..  It has thrown very generic exception, given below..

```
System.ServiceModel.FaultException: The workflow has been aborted.

at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)

at System.ServiceModel.Activities.Dispatcher.ControlOperationInvoker.InvokeEnd(Object instance, Object[]& outputs, IAsyncResult result)

at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeEnd(MessageRpc& rpc)

at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage7(MessageRpc& rpc)

at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)
```

Below are the steps..

I have developed the sample workflow service using framework 4.5  ( set the  Definition Identity too )

named CusotmerService.xamlx.

Hosted in App fabric

Updated the persistence store schema too (SqlWorkflowInstanceStoreSchemaUpgrade.sql)

Before start making the changes to the existing workflow definition , done the following changes

Created the App_Code folder ->  Moved the existing work defintion(CustomerService.Xamlx) to this folder.

And also renamed it to CustomerServiceV1.xamlx.

Then after that I have made changes to CustomerService.xamlx  ( Added one extra Assign Activity)

Modified the Defintion Identity ( changed the version to 2.0.0.0)

Then I published my changes to IIS ( Publish) ( restarted the IIS too after published..)

As soon as I published my changes to IIS then the persisted workflows broke.  New instances worked without any issues..

I'm not sure why it broke..  Is there any way to publish the side by side workflow services in IIS / Appfabric? Am I doing anything wrong here... Please advice me..

Appreciate your quick response..

Thanks

Deepa

Answer (score 0):

a) Reading through the MS documentation suggests that moving the XAMLX to the AppCode folder is not correct. It should be moved to a subfolder with the same name as the service:

create a new folder in the App_Code folder that has the same name as the service file. If the service’s xamlx file is named MortgageWorkflow.xamlx, then the folder must be named MortgageWorkflow. Place a copy of the original service’s xamlx file into this folder and rename it to a new name, such as MortgageWorkflowV1.xamlx

b) To diagnose the aborted exception, typically you go to AppFabric service configuration and enable verbose tracing on both WCF and WF. You will see the root cause there.

Comment: Sorry,  I didnt explain properly... I had created the  folder  with name  CustomerService ( as my service name is CustomerService.xamlx) under App_Code  and then moved the original workflow definition to this folder.. Anyways I will enable the trace and check it..

Comment: Usually a sudden workflow aborted record means that some very severe exception occured so early on that the wf instance was not able to track it properly. Enable verbose WCF and WF logging, try the message tracing too - also google for the Application Server Analytics windows event log, enable it and look in there